# Mocking Bigquery for integration tests

Tags: java, google-bigquery, integration-testing

While other interfaces are relatively easy to mock in my Java integration tests, I couldn't find a proper way of mocking Bigquery.

One possibility is to mock the layer I wrote on top of Bigquery itself, but I prefer mocking Bigquery in a more natural way. I'm looking for a limited, lightweight implementation, which allows defining the table contents, and supports queries using the standard API.
Is there such a library? If not, what alternative approaches are recommended?

Answer (score 11):

In unit testing it is perfectly fine to mock all external dependencies, and as long you are using interfaces to abstract out access to BigQuery client, mocking should not be an issue.

With integration testing I would rather get all my 3rd parties dependencies tested
to the extend an application needs it.

For instance one case would be an ETL which streams data from external sources to BigQuery, in this case an integration test needs to verify that all data is in BigQuery as expected, which means that verification stage needs to take into account repeated, and nested messages as required.

Another case would an application that runs some business SQLs, in this case  you would have populate BigQuery with some test data before applicaiton run, 
then the applicaiton needs to publishe the SQL output either as  view/new table/or stream out of data out of for verification.

There are already some libraries taking care of integration testing with datastores including BigQuery/NoSQL/SQL

They would provide an easy solution for the cases described above and full support for SQL, dynamic macro/predicate etc ....

1. [Dsunit](https://github.com/viant/dsunit)  (go-lang)
2. [JDsunit](https://github.com/viant/jdsunit) (java)
3. [Endly](http://github.com/viant/endly/)(language agnostic)

See more how to use [endly](https://medium.com/@adrianwit/etl-end-to-end-testing-with-docker-nosql-rdbms-and-big-query-35b13b7fada8) for ETL and BiqQuery testing

If datastore integration test library is not an option for you and you are looking for just testing BigQuery client, the good news is that the client uses REST, so using network sniffers you can easy record what is being send back and forth, then you can use it in replayer. In order to redirect BigQuery from 
public BG endpoints to your replayer you would use http java proxy.

Comment: Do I need to install go-lang for JDSUnit ? Also the introduction says that we need to install DSUnit server , what is that ?

Comment: You would need to install golang, jdsunit is just simple rest client for dsunit server which is actually responsible for data preparation and verification

Comment: Sorry , its not clear does dsunit server get installed automatically  when I install golang ? Which component communicates with BigQuery , is it jdsunit client or dsunit server ? Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: DsUnit server in go-lang communicates with BigQuery. Looks like jdsunit Config has auto install and runLocally options, which if they are set, then it pulls, builds and runs dsunit server (if golang is installed).

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Witas, can you please point me to installation directions for jdsunit?